# Do not refresh the applet in web page when page refresh from server or any other suggestion?

Tags: javascript, applet, voip

I have website where I have implemented the functionality to call dialing and call receiving using voip services. I'm using applet JAR file for call operation. Now if call is running and I refresh the page then call is getting disconnected that is ok. I need to implement the function where if call comes in to website then page will be reloaded in background and it will display the caller information. Now if page is refreshed  then call is getting disconnected.

Is there any way to not reload the applet or any other way by which call will not disconnect and agent will play with the website in background?

Comment: mine is in perspective of javascript and @user592704 is in perspective of applet :) hope both helps

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to not reload the applet or any other way by which
>   call will not disconnect and agent will play with the website in
>   background?

As far as my knowledge goes, there is **NO WAY** you can stop from executing a refresh when the user clicks the refresh button on his browser bar. If that had happened, it would be an invasion of his privacy and also a security breach.

On a side note: There is a method to [warn users when a webpage tries to redirect/reload](http://www.mydigitallife.info/stop-and-disable-web-pages-auto-refresh-or-reload-in-firefox/) on its own (such as a meta redirect), but that doesnt solve your problem as the client has to do it manually, *and* is alerted when you *intentionally* redirect the client.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I am not pretty sure about a standard way the effect you want to achieve but I have faced the thing but in my case I was trying to solve it backward I mean make applet "being refreshed" its UI when it needed :) 
The effect you describe in your question can be achieved by using static Swing components because standard JRE applet cache re-load setting (which should reload jre on each Internet Browser applet web page is refreshed), as a rule, set to "**false**"

---

You can see the non-reload effect by using, as an example, static JPanel in your applet

Here some idea tips...
    ...

```
static JPanel aPanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
static int i;
...

init()
{
...
aPanel.add(new JLabel("Hello World, say "+(++i)));
}
```

---

refresh your applet web page a few times and see what happens. Hope that helps

Good luck